# expression has type 'a list -> 'b list but an expression was expected of type 'b list

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

This is my function

```
let rec helper inputList = function
  | [] -> []
  | a :: b :: hd -> 
    if a = b then helper ([b::hd]) 
    else a :: helper (b::hd)
```

It's not complete, however I can't see why I keep getting the error in the title at helper ([b::hd]). I've tried helper (b::hd) or helper (b::hd::[]) however all come up with errors. How do I make it so that it works?

Comment: Because all recursive calls pop the head of the list, so eventually that list contains one element.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `function` you are supplying a pattern for the parameter of the function. But you already have a parameter named `inputList`. So this function `helper` is expecting two parameters (but it ignores the first).

You can fix this by removing `inputList`.

You also have a problem in your first recursive call to `helper`. Your expression `[b :: hd]` is a list of lists. I suspect that you want something more like just `b :: hd` here.

There is at least one other problem, but I hope this helps get you started.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors here. One is that the keyword `function` means we have an implicit parameter over which we are working. So the pattern matching happens on that "invisible" parameter. But here you defined probably the explicit one: `inputList`. So we can remove that one:

```
let rec helper = function
  | [] -> []
  | a :: b :: hd -> if a = b then helper ([b::hd]) else a :: helper (b:: hd)
```

Next there is a problem with the types: in the recursion, you use:

1. `helper ([b::hd])`; and
2. `a :: helper (b:: hd)`

But you put these on the same line, and that makes no sense, since the first one passes a *list of lists of elements*, and the second a *list of elements*. So the result of the first one would be a *list of list of elements*, and the second one a *list of elements*. It does not make sense to merge these.

If I understood correctly that you want to ensure that no two consecutive elements should occur that are equal, then we should rewrite it to:

```
let rec helper = function
  | [] -> []
  | a :: b :: hd -> if a = b then helper (b::hd) else a :: helper (b:: hd)
```

You have defined two patterns here:

1. one for the empty list; and
2. one for a list with *at least* two elements.

The second one will perform recursion on the tail of the list `b :: hd`. So that means that eventually when we pass it a list with *n* elements, it will recursively work on a list with *n-1* elements, *n-2* elements, etc. But eventually it will have one element. And there is no case for that. So we need to add a case for the one element pattern:

```
let rec helper = function
  | [] -> []
  | h :: [] -> h :: []
  | a :: b :: hd -> if a = b then helper (b::hd) else a :: helper (b:: hd)
```